# Add element to a nested hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
a = { 21 => { 3 => {:x => 5, :y => 6}}}
```

I want to add another value to the key '21' so that the hash looks like this:

```
a = { 21 => { 3 => {:x => 5, :y => 6}, 4 => {:x => 8, :y => 7}}}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add an key-value pair to a hash (`a[21]`). `a[21]` will give you the inner hash object.

```
a = { 21 => { 3 => {:x => 5, :y => 6}}}
a[21]
# => {3=>{:x=>5, :y=>6}}
```

Associating key, values to the inner hash will solve your problem.

```
a[21][4] = {:x => 8, :y => 7}
a
# => {21=>{3=>{:x=>5, :y=>6}, 4=>{:x=>8, :y=>7}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is:

```
a[21].update({ 4=>{:x => 8, :y => 7} }) 

a #=> {21=>{3=>{:x=>5, :y=>6}, 4=>{:x=>8, :y=>7}}}
```